Can physicalists with a straight face say that the challenges they've got in their personal life are all random and not carefully calibrated?
I understand that the inclination to analyze your life and key events that brought you where you are, is not universal, but to some degree, most people do look back in order to see logical reasons that structured their life.
So my question is, can those consistent materialists be true to themselves and confirm that they are 100% sure that physical illnesses, school bullying, broken heart from first love, aggressive peer pressure at work, and many other challenges in life - were not carefully calibrated to what they could handle and overcome?

Explanation has to stop somewhere unless you believe in infinite regress. What gives deeper meaning to the universe you think? Whatever that is, what makes that not unexplained or random?

So the weather is carefully calibrated to match what I can overcome?  It explains why I haven't experienced a tornado. I couldn't handle that.

"carefully calibrated"? by a supernatural angel? But the real question is: What do you mean by "overcome"? It's hard to overcome being imprisoned or being shot dead.

@mudskipper It's hard to overcome being imprisoned May I suggest a a small dose of Victor Frankl: Everything can be taken from a man but one thing: the last of the human freedoms—to choose one’s attitude in any given set of circumstances, to choose one’s own way If you then add "shot" one could retort Jesus. Or Socrates

You seem to be under the mistaken assumption that people don’t frequently encounter things they can’t “handle” well (death of a loved one, drug addiction, getting fired, car accidents, assault, severe depression, schizophrenia, natural disasters, terrorism, etc etc etc etc etc). Accounting for that, there doesn’t seem to be much calibration, does there? If everything that doesn’t kill you (i.e. all that) can “be handled”, then of course this is just survivorship bias, and Mazement’s answer is exactly correct. Some people do die of illness; how would that be calibrated?

TL; DR: Yes, they can and they will and they do.

Looking back didn't do Lot's wife much good.

Reminder: please do other people the courtesy of assuming that they have thought as deeply about their worldview as you have about yours, and accepting that they believe what they say they believe, even if you don't understand how they reached that conclusion.

There is no such thing as a consistent materialist.
In the 19th century they called themselves positivists.Then changed to 'materialists' in the 20th century when embarrassed that the positivist guru Comte founded a Church.
Then people started to notice:

Can those consistent materialists be true to themselves and confirm that they are 100% sure that physical illnesses...

Materialists cannot be consistent — logic is not matter.
Materialists cannot be true — truth is not matter.
Materialists cannot be ill — there are only electrons, protons etc that are in effect eternal.
Etc
For me personally the most ironic thing about materialism is that they choose their 'religion' on a monistic compulsion — There's only one reality electrons.... Or atoms... Or whatever
But they never succeed in becoming real monists — because there remains always two — the hard-as-nails physics and the soft-as-wetware physicist.
So in the 21st cetury, when materialists noticed that others were noticing these glaring facts they changed their name to physicalists thinking that by these subterfuges their nonsense would not be noticed.
They seem to think that by leaving an undefined term — physical — or by circular definition — physics in terms of physical, physical in terms of physics we will all be fooled.
They've been doing surprisingly well for a good century.
Now people are beginning to wake up.

On the other hand, I do go to doctors — trained materialistically.
Use cars, elevators... zillions of other things all made/conceived on materialistic base.
Teach computer science — a strange limbo — information between the matter world and the psychological world.
So in practice I am a dualist although as a philosophy dualism is an admission of defeat.
However as you correctly intuit the very meaning of meaning disappears on an uncompromising materialistic base.

Added Later
This answer alleges that this answer is not an answer.
So let me articulate again
In logic, an inconsistent system can prove anything.
Those proofs however however pack no punch because they mean nothing
So materialists can say whatever they like because they're inconsistent.
A sharper way of saying this is to grok the polysemy of "say"
One meaning of say is to talk/write etc.
In that sense they certainly can say
Another meaning of "say" is to mean something.
Since the materialist by definition rejects the entire Platonic realm of Consistency, Truth and Meaning (not to mention the "higher" Platonic forms — Justice, Beauty, Love... and ultimately the Good) they cannot say anything.
To this answer my response:
You're focusing exclusively on the lowest tier — survival —of the Maslow hierarchy where the answer works.
If however you understand 'calibrate' as 'calibrate across Maslow' it fails
for all higher levels

whatever consciousness is, it depends on the physical. We know this with certainty since it doesn’t seem to be present when the brain is dead

@Syed - We cannot explain most of the fundamental observations in our reality. But, as Rushi says, you can use this inability to explain as vindication of 'any' of your particular views.

[In the 19th century they called themselves positivists. Then changed to 'materialists' in the 20th century... in the 21st cetury .... they changed their name to physicalists] I don't think this is true. Materialism was a 19th century name contemporary with positivism, and physicalism a 20th century version.

“people are beginning to wake up” - are they? Matter is completely described by math which is completely described by logic. So the very first of your points seems moot.

@gs  In an exact sense — yes. I was not referring to the point of origin so much as what term is generally fashionable in thar period

This is a literal example of "survivorship bias": If a person is alive, then they've overcome all the challenges they faced; but if they're dead, then they've faced a challenge they couldn't handle - perhaps illness, or heartbreak, or stress at work or school.
If we assume that all challenges are calibrated to be survivable, then that's got unsavory implications: If a child dies of cancer, we'd be forced to believe that they could have overcome cancer if they'd only tried harder.
So it must be that some challenges are calibrated to be survivable, and others aren't. A materialist would say, "If we can't find any sort of pattern, then there's no reason to believe it's calibrated - it might be completely random."

Life and death, black and white. Yes, in this simplified view of reality, you can feel perfectly comfortable with your physicalist views.

The argument still works if you add complexity. Like if someone gets a a disease that weakens them without killing them, and then dies of a second disease that they could have otherwise survived. A physicalist would just say that there's no evidence that either disease was "calibrated"

Folk wisdom (experience of generations) would disagree, but physicalists don't care in their blind confidence.

“If a child dies of cancer, we'd be forced to believe that they could have overcome cancer if they'd only tried harder” is the thing that isn’t addressed by any counter argument here. If it’s calibrated to what we can overcome, then the only reason anyone fails at handling anything is just because they didn’t try hard enough, even when some people physically could not try any harder than they currently are, which is of course contradictory.

@controlgroup - Why do you bring death and terminal disease as an argument? This is an end of the game. But you can find some logic in any scenario. It is just a matter of personal preferences: very shaky scientific understanding of human consciousness vs no less shaky human intuition.

My point remains - why should some experiences be calibrated and others just be “the end of the game”? Obviously you will perceive everything as being calibrated to be able to be handled if you discard every circumstance where it can’t be handled as “the end of the game.” Obviously every case will appear to have properly A if you discard every case where it doesn’t. That’s survivorship bias - precisely what Mazement says.

@controlgroup - The balance of life and death, suffering and perseverance, achievement and failures. Human pain as the common denominator and human love as the highest reward. You would rather read good literature than listen to me.  :)

I fail to see how that’s related. And seeing the opinions some people at the top and some people at the bottom of society, love is not necessarily the highest reward (some people prefer money, fame, just to have their own opinions propagated). My point stands: everything will obviously seem calibrated if you discard all the obviously-uncalibrated circumstances as just part of the “balance”.

@controlgroup - Those people did not have a chance to experience something great in their lives. So they are settled for what they know, unaware that this is a life on a minimal diet of Endorphins.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Yes.
Whatever categories you have in mind under the labels "physicalists" or "consistent materialists"* (and for that matter, people following almost any other metaphysical belief system), there are people within those categories that can "say with a straight face that the challenges they've got in their personal life are all random and not carefully calibrated."
Although if being careful, one should avoid usually avoid claiming that they are "100% sure" about anything. See generally, Baron Reed, "Certainty" in Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy.

* Another answer takes issue with whether there are even people that could be considered "consistent materialists" and avoids answering the question asked. But since you're not asking whether there are such people, I take it as a given that the category of people you're asking about is not empty, even if they might not accurately be described as "consistent materialists." My answer would stand no matter the label.
